# How to convert base64 artifact to json/yaml in spinnaker?

Tags: pipeline, kubernetes-helm, spinnaker

I'm trying to use the SpEL in Spinnaker pipeline to convert an artifact from base64 to JSON because I want to retrieve some field from that manifest. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#fromBase64(string)` and `#readJson(string)` helpers